# Alternative to <context> in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, alias, contextpath

I have a deployed application in Tomcat 7, and I need to have some "aliases" to this app with different urls. Like this:

```
server/mainapp
server/customer1
server/customer2
server/customer3
server/customer4
server/customerN
```

To implement this, have used several "< context>" entries in server.xml, like:

```
<Context path="/customer1" docBase="webapps/mainapp" />
<Context path="/customer2" docBase="webapps/mainapp" />
```

and so on.

Is this the right way to solve it? I've observed that the more "< context>" I define, the more time is needed to server to start and more memory is allocated (sometimes causing a PermGen OutOfMemory error). Is there a way to just create some "shurtcut" url to mainapp?

Comment: Creating multiple Contexts will create multiple webapps (which is why it's slow to start and uses more memory). You want one webapp with multiple aliases right? Should each "alias" show the same content?

Comment: Yes. The aliases will display the same content. It's in fact one single application, but every customer have access to an exclusive url, wich is used by the application to identify it.

Comment: It depends how your app works - static content/servlets/spring controllers? You could map multiple servlet mappings to the same servlet for example... One common solution is to use an Apache HTTP server with URL rewrites forwarding requests to your tomcat server. You could probably find a URL rewrite filter you could use in your webapp too...

Comment: It's a struts app, and it is a bit complex application. I can't use an Apache in front of Tomcat, because it is hosted on a Tomcat only environment. Is there any alternative for me to do what I need or multiple contexts it's the only way?

Comment: Try searching for an example using a URL rewrite filter in Java/Tomcat - you could include that in your webapp. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks MattR. I'll take a look at some URL rewrite filter. I'll let you know if I have any success.